Class member function returning another class: works for getting a class variable, but not for setting a class variable
Somewhere there seems to be an implied const that is not allowing getSubsiaryClass() when changing a variable member of the SubsidiaryClass, but it works fine for reading a variable.  It isn't a public/private issue, I've looked at that.  Why do the 2nd and 3rd approaches work, but the 1st does not?
Can anyone help me understand why this happens? [or tell me where I can find the answer, this is my first post and I'm unsure of the protocol]
#include <iostream>

class SubsidiaryClass {

    private:
        double                 little_double;

    public:
        double                 getLittleDouble()                                      {return little_double;}
        void                   putLittleDouble(double input)                          {little_double = input; return;}
};

class ParentClass {

    private:
        double                 little_double;
        SubsidiaryClass        subsidiary_class;
 
    public:
        double                 getLittleDouble()                                      {return little_double;}
        void                   putLittleDouble(double input)                          {little_double = input; return;}

        SubsidiaryClass        getSubsidiaryClass()                                   {return subsidiary_class;}
        SubsidiaryClass&       getSubsidiaryClassReference()                          {return subsidiary_class;}
        SubsidiaryClass*       getSubsidiaryClassPointer()                            {return &subsidiary_class;}

};

int main() {

    ParentClass parent_class;
  
    parent_class.getSubsidiaryClass().putLittleDouble(1.1);                                    // does not work, no error message 
    std::cout << parent_class.getSubsidiaryClass().getLittleDouble() << std::endl;

    parent_class.getSubsidiaryClassReference().putLittleDouble(2.2);                          // works fine
    std::cout << parent_class.getSubsidiaryClassReference().getLittleDouble() << std::endl;
    std::cout << parent_class.getSubsidiaryClass().getLittleDouble() << std::endl;

    parent_class.getSubsidiaryClassPointer() -> putLittleDouble(3.3);    // works fine
    std::cout << parent_class.getSubsidiaryClassPointer() -> getLittleDouble() << std::endl;    // works fine
    std::cout << parent_class.getSubsidiaryClass().getLittleDouble() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}


Well, are you aware what SubsidiaryClass& and SubsidiaryClass* mean relative to SubsidiaryClass? Replace SubsidiaryClass with int. What would you then expect to happen when writing parent_class.getSubsidiaryClassX() = 1?

what is the code supposed to do? What does it do instead? How do the two differ? What do you mean with "not work" ? We can only see the code and what it does. You expect it to do something else but you need to tell us what that is

C++ has value semantics: Every time you declare something to have type T without &, including a return value, it will cause the declared thing to be its own object, i.e. its own instance of the given type T. Something of type T never refers to another object/instance of type T. When initializing a T from an expression of the same type, C++ does this by implicit copying (or moving) the state of the source object into the new object. If one wants a reference to some already existing object in C++, one must use references (&) (or pointers). That's what they are for.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've already taken the [Tour], so you're a significant step up on most folks. Here's a bit of reading to ease you in to how things work here: [ask], the asking questions portion of the Help Center to get more details, and Writing the Perfect Question. Also worth reading How to debug small programs for tips on how to avoid asking questions in the first place.

So the returned object in SubsidiaryClass        getSubsidiaryClass()  can't be the SubsidiaryClass object that is a member subobject of your ParentClass. It is a copy of it. When you modify that copy with .putX, it has no relation to the original object.

related

getSubsidiaryClass() returns a SubsidiaryClass object by value, so it returns a copy of the original object.  You are then calling putLittleDouble() on that copy, so any modifications made to it are not reflected back in the original object.  That is why calling getLittleDouble() afterwards (on a new copy) does not return the new value.
That is not the case when using getSubsidiaryClassReference() and getSubsidiaryClassPointer(), as they are returning a reference/pointer to the original object, so you are modifying the original object directly, not a copy of it.  And then calling getLittleDouble() afterwards (on a new copy) returns the modified value.
If you add logging to your SubsidiaryClass class, you can easily see the creation and destruction of these copied objects, eg:
class SubsidiaryClass {

    private:
        double little_double;

    public:
        SubsidiaryClass() : little_double(0.0) {
            std::cout << "Def Create: " << this << '\n';
        }

        SubsidiaryClass(const SubsidiaryClass &src) : little_double(src.little_double) {
            std::cout << "Copy Create: " &src << " -> " << this << '\n';
        }
        
        ~SubsidiaryClass() {
            std::cout << "Destroy: " << this << '\n';
        }

        double getLittleDouble() {
            std::cout << "Returning value from " << this << '\n';
            return little_double;
        }

        void putLittleDouble(double input) {
            std::cout << "Setting value for " << this << '\n';
            little_double = input; return;
        }
};

Online Demo

Cool, thanks so much!
